# Question in Redux's doc with regard to createSelector and createEntityAdapter

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

On the page:
[doc](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization)

This section:
[image]
states that `dispatch(reactionAdded())` won't cause the component to re-render as `posts` is not changed here. But it seems `reactionAdded` does mutate one of the `posts` cause the entire `posts` array to be replaced by a new one.

Another question:
[image]
Does it mean value returned by <del>`selectById`</del> `selectIds` from `createEntityAdapter` will always return the same array(unchanged reference) as long as all `id`s of entity are unchanged even if content of `entities` memeber is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. I wrote that tutorial, and it's entirely possible I made a mental mistake when writing that example.  Yeah, `reactionAdded` does update a post entry, which would also mean that there *should* be a new `posts` array generated as a result because of the immutable updates.  Probably need to come up with a different example there :)

And yes, `selectById` always does a straight lookup - ie, `return state.posts.entities[postId]`, so there's no derived data involved.  It just returns that *one* item by itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But I made a mistake in the question(edited to fix).
In the second question, I was meant to ask whether the id array returned as the same reference as long as ids do not change(probably a redux-toolkit question) even if a single "post" entity is mutated.

Comment: Correct. The IDs array will not change unless items are actually added or removed (or an item has its actual ID modified).  Changes to other fields in items will not modify the IDs array, because there's still an item with that ID. The exception to this is sorting - if there is a sort callback supplied, and the item field change causes the sort order to change, the IDs array will be updated to match the sort ordering.